# FireBreath + CodeBlocks link library

Tags: c++, codeblocks, firebreath

I need to link a shared library in a FireBreath project in CodeBlocks.

I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
set(LIBRARY_PATH "/usr/lib")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PLUGIN_INTERNAL_DEPS} debug "${LIBRARY_PATH}/lib.so")
```

What can i do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be more precise in your description: what is the error message ?

Comment: and are you sure you're building in debug mode, given that you've specified only a library for debug mode and haven't specified one for release?